# How to populate a ComboBox based on another ComboBox using a connection string (SQL Server, VB.NET)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, combobox

When a user selects a client from combobox 1 (a company we do work with and are partners with), its supposed to populate the users from combobox 2 for that client only, which needs to come from that particular database in SQL Server.

Example:

The first Combobox with all the Clients when a user selects a client and the Second ComboBox with all the Users from that database only, I want the Users list of the Second ComboBox to change according to the Clients selected from the list of the first ComboBox, but including a connection string, via SQL Server.

So if I select say....Google in Combobox 1 and in Combobox 2, I expect say.....10 users from Google. But if I change my mind and select Yahoo in Combobox 1 and in  Combobox 2, I expect say..... this time around 12 users from Yahoo.

Database Name I'm using: **MyDatabase**

Get the users from these databases, based on the selection I make, which contains those particular users, not MyDatabase which has users as well:

- GoogleQA (If user selected Google, get the users from this database only and populate it during runtime)
- YahooQA (If user selected Yahoo, get the users from this database only and populate it during runtime)

My VB.Net code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conStr").ConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from CLIENTS", con)
        con.Open()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
        con.Close()
        cboClient.DataSource = dt
        cboClient.DisplayMember = "CLIENT_NAME"
        cboClient.ValueMember = "ID"

        rtfMessage.Tag = "Enter your message here"
        rtfMessage.Text = CStr(rtfMessage.Tag)
```

What can I put in my comboboxes code to get the end goal of what I want to happen:

```
  Private Sub cboUser_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboUser.SelectedValueChanged
--What do I put here?
    End Sub

Private Sub cboClient_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboClient.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conStr2").ConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from USERS", con)
        con.Open()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
        con.Close()
        cboClient.DataSource = dt
        cboClient.DisplayMember = "NetworkID"
        cboClient.ValueMember = "ID"
        cboClient.Text = ""
        If cboClient.SelectedItem.Text = "Sunoco" Then
            cboUser.Items.Add("NetworkID")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Possibility: On client change combo box function (cboClient_SelectedValueChanged)

```
1.) Change the database connection
2.) Query the proper user data from the correct database
3.) populate the user combo box with that user data
```

Comment: So every time either combo box changes, you want to get data from your table? Also what do you mean by "but including a connection string..."? What do you want to include it in? I think you should try to describe what you're trying to do a bit more clearly.

Comment: Just when the Combobox 1 (Clients) changes, it should show users from that particular database only. Just like how I have a connection string for the clients which populates about 6 records when I run it, if I select that client, then Combobox 2 should list all of the users from the client I selected (and from that database only).

Comment: You can see I have SQL variables set up for the Clients, but I want to do that for the users too, but to get the data from that database (or client that I select on the UI).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having a really hard time understanding what you're wanting. I also don't know what you mean when you say clients and users, or what relationship they hold to each other. I think more information, like your table(s) structure(s), is needed.

Comment: Okay. I edited. Does this make more sense now?

Answer (score 0):

You just do what you have done in the load section in an if statement inside your user section.

sort of like :

```
    `If cboClient.SelectedItem.Text = "Google" then
     (code to populate the other combobox with google info)
     End if`


     `If cboClient.SelectedItem.Text = "Yahoo" then 
        dim sql as string = "Select firstName+ " " +lastname as empName from 
        Yahoo table"
        dim cmd as sqladapter(sql, con)
        dim dt as datatable
        cmd.fill(dt)
        cboUsers.datasource = dt
        cboUsers.Datatextfield = "empName"
        cboUsers.Datavaluefield = "empName"
        cboUsers.DataBind()
     End if


        Dim sql2 As String = "Select EQPnumber, EQPdesc from CREW_LINEUP_ACTIVE_EQUIPMENT"
        Dim activeEQPadt As New SqlDataAdapter(sql2, IPMS.Settings.conn)
        activeEQPadt.Fill(activeDT)
        ActiveEQPLstBx.DataSource = activeDT
        ActiveEQPLstBx.DataTextField = "EQPdesc"
        ActiveEQPLstBx.DataValueField = "EQPnumber"
        ActiveEQPLstBx.DataBind()
```

Comment: Can you make this a little more readable please and possibly expand on your answer? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: inside your cboClients_selectedIndexChanged subroutine,  'if cboClient.SelectedItem.Text = "Google" then                                                          (this is your code to populate the user cboBox with google users which should be similar to how you populated the client box originally)                    End if'                                                                                                          'if cbo.client.selecteditem.text = "yahoo" then                                               (code to populate client box) End if'

Comment: "code to populate the other combobox with yahoo info"

What is the correct code to write if I select Yahoo and get the users from YahooQA? Like I have tblyahoo with test data in it.

Comment: well that would depend on what your table columns were and how they were related to one another

Comment: I have alot but I want to combine the First Name and Last Name together from that tblyahoo table. So What's the correct code to write. Can you edit your answer please?

Comment: Something like this:

cboUser.Items.Add("NetworkID") --> NetworkID contains the first and last name by the way. It's combined into one.

SEE THE UPDATED CODE!

Comment: You have to bind the data to the box in order to fill it. You can add the items one by one but i suggest tweaking your sql statement to only pull what you want to display in that box, binding that data to the cboBox, and then it should display all of the values that you want it to. Use if statements to set your conditions on how you want to pull info from the database and it will make things alot more straightforward and simple for when you need to populate the comboBox.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I put in it the cboUser subrountine and nothing happened. Are you sure that's right?

Comment: The syntax isn't going to be exact since I only know a very small portion of the data that you're working with and trying to manipulate, but yes that's the general format of how I populate ComboBoxes, Listboxes, and dropdownlists. I'll put an example of how I have bound my data in the past in my original post.

Comment: But where am I inserting those If statements in: cboClient or cboUser?

Comment: cboClient, that is the one you are wanting to fire changes off of. The cboUser is just being populated by what cboClient calls on changes